# Shell comand over HTML working only with some inputs

Tags: php, html, shell

i use an HTML page to send pigpiod shell commands to my Raspberry Pi 3 to change the colours of an RGB strip using pigpiod and it works. 
Now I want to implement a text to speech using the same php/shell script but it does not work as the pigpiod one.

I think the problem is in the variable, but i don't get where.

I set the variables and look for them at the very beginning of the index.php file

```
<?php

$c=$_GET['c'];
$r=$_GET['r'];
$g=$_GET['g'];
$b=$_GET['b'];
$testo=$_GET['testo'];

if($c == 1)
{
        $execute = shell_exec("pigpiod");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs w 12 0");
        sleep(1);
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs w 12 1");
        header('Location: http://192.168.2.123/cancello/');
}

if($r != "" AND $g != "" AND $b != "")
{
        $execute = shell_exec("pigpiod");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 22 $r");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 27 $g");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 17 $b");
        header('Location: http://192.168.2.123/cancello/');
}

if($testo != "")
{
        $execute = shell_exec("./speech.sh $testo");
        header('Location: http://192.168.2.123/cancello/');
}

?>
```

Then after other code i get the RGB input (which works) and the text to speech one (which does not)

```
    <a href="index.php?r=0&g=100&b=100"  class="button0 buttonacqua"></a>
    <a href="index.php?r=100&g=100&b=100"  class="button0 buttonbianco"></a>

    <form action="index.php" method ="get">
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="text" name="text">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I see the form and I can input text, but when i confirm it does not work.

This is the speech.sh code that works when i run it by console using "./speech.sh and some text to speak"

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$*
STRINGNUM=0
ary=($INPUT)
for key in "${!ary[@]}"
  do
    SHORTTMP[$STRINGNUM]="${SHORTTMP[$STRINGNUM]} ${ary[$key]}"
    LENGTH=$(echo ${#SHORTTMP[$STRINGNUM]})
    #echo "word:$key, ${ary[$key]}"
    #echo "adding to: $STRINGNUM"
    if [[ "$LENGTH" -lt "100" ]]; then
      #echo starting new line
      SHORT[$STRINGNUM]=${SHORTTMP[$STRINGNUM]}
    else
      STRINGNUM=$(($STRINGNUM+1))
      SHORTTMP[$STRINGNUM]="${ary[$key]}"
      SHORT[$STRINGNUM]="${ary[$key]}"
    fi
done
for key in "${!SHORT[@]}"
  do
    #echo "line: $key is: ${SHORT[$key]}"
    NEXTURL=$(echo ${SHORT[$key]} | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g')
    mpg123 -q "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&q=$NEXTURL&tl=It-it"

done
```

Comment: Try changing `$execute = shell_exec("./speech.sh $testo");` to `$execute = shell_exec("bash ./speech.sh $testo");`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks but it's now working anyway. Now i'm sure the variable is read by the system (i see the url variation with my text) but the shell script does not start. So the issue must be in the execution